# regular expression : capture groups titles (between square bracket) dans the content of each groups

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Given a file where we find a variable numbers of 'group' and each group has a content.

- a line can contain a title between squares brackets
- and, bellow each groups titles, we have the content of the group. The content of the group hasn't restriction about char contained. A line in a content must not begin by the char '[' (a line that starts with '[' is a title of a group)

Bellow an example of a file following theses rules :

```
[titleOfgroup1]
foo
faafaa [ddfdf]

fii
[title of group2]

faa fii@@
<tag1>fuu</tag1>

    foo1234

wdw

dwd

[title of [group3]]
faa faa
[titleOfGroup4]

fiifoo
```

I'm looking for capture with REGEX all titles groups and all contents foreach group captured. The result expected after REGEX work :

```
GROUP 1 : 
    MATCH 1 : 'titleOfgroup1'
    MATCH 2 : 'foo
faafaa [ddfdf]

fii'

GROUP 2 : 
    MATCH 1 : 'title of group2'
    MATCH 2 : 'faa fii@@
<tag1>fuu</tag1>

    foo1234'

GROUP 3 : 
    MATCH 1 : 'title of [group3]'
    MATCH 2 : 'faa faa'

GROUP 4 : 
    MATCH 1 : 'titleOfGroup4'
    MATCH 2 : 'fiifoo'
```

I tried some REGEX and Im close to the solution but Im stuck. My last try is this REGEX : `^\[(.*)\]\n[\s]*([\S\s]*?)[\s]*(?=\n\[)` ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/ZjYAFR/1))

but as you can see, this REGEX can't capture the last group :

[image]

How can I get the last group ? thanks for any help !

(ps : im looking for a regex who works on javascript and php)

Comment: Think if you make the ending optional it will work `((?=(\n)\[)|\Z)`. Is https://regex101.com/r/6oSaxt/1 correct? ... well works for PCRE, looks like JS doesn't have `\Z` though.

Comment: aaa I didin't know \Z ! indeed, that works like a charm ! thx you !

Comment: Think https://regex101.com/r/kZdSTq/1 works for PHP and JS.

Comment: Maybe [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/kjOVqs/2) is helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not matching the last line, because the last part in your pattern `(?=\n\[)` asserts that there must be a newline followed by `[` present.

What you could do instead is capture the title in group 1, and then in group 2 match all lines that do not start with `[` using a negative lookahead after matching a newline

```
^\[(.+)\]\n((?:(?!\[).*(?:\n|$))*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\[(.+)\]` Match `[` capture the title in **group 1** and match `]`
- `\n` Match a newline (or \r?\n)
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `(?!\[)` Negative lookahead, assert not `[` to the right
    - `.*(?:\n|$)` Match the whole line and either a newline or assert the end of the string
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it to match all lines
- `)` Close group 2

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aN7ImQ/1).